# Non-isotrival fiber bundle over compact Riemann surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces

In [this paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/kodaira1.pdf), Kodaira constructed a fiber bundle $\Phi:M_{m,n}\to S$ from a compact complex surface $M_{m,n}$ to a compact Rieman surface $S$ of genus $>0$. In particular, (on p.212) for any point $u\in S$, the fibre $C_u =\Phi^{-1}(u)$ is a compact Riemann surface
which is an $m$-sheeted cyclic (branched) covering surface of $R$ with two branch points, where $R$ is a compact Riemann surface of genus $\not=0$. I want to know why this fiber bundle is not isotrivial.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kodaira's examples have index $\tau>0$. If $M\to S$ were isotrivial, then it is not hard to see that after pulling back to a finite unramified cover of $S$, the surface becomes a product. But this would  force $\tau(M)=0$ [See added note below].
You can look at the book *Compact Complex Surfaces* by Barth, (Hulek), Peters, and Van de Venn for further explanation.

There are examples of what are sometimes called Kodaira surfaces, where nonisotriviallity  is essentially immediate. Namely, find a compact curve $S$ in $M_g$ (which exists once $g>2$), and pull back the "universal" curve.

**Added Explanation** The index is the signature of the intersection form. By a theorem of Hirzebruch, it can also be computed as
$$\tau(M)= \frac{1}{3}(c_1^2(M)-2c_2(M))$$
It follows that if $M'\to M$ is a finite unramified cover, then $\tau(M')=0$ if and only if $\tau(M)=0$. In particular, if $M'$ can be chosen as  a product of curves, then it can be checked that $\tau(M')=0$, so $\tau(M)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but how to see that Kodaira's examples have index $\tau>0$?

Comment: Kodaira's paper that you linked  says "The purpose of this note is to exhibit a series of compact connected complex 4-manfolds ... with positive indices." You should read it.

Comment: Sorry, I checked the book you mentioned but still one some questions, I can see the pullback as the product of curves has index $0$, but why would that imply $\tau(M)=0$? Is index invariant under base change?

Comment: OK, I'll expand my answer.